# Updating PHP to 7.2.5 on Mac for Laravel 7 / Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, macos, homestead

Can anyone help me with this issue, I have spent all day trying to fix this problem!

I have an existing Homestead / Virtualbox development environment on my Mac, which has worked well on a number of Laravel projects.

I am now setting up a new project using Laravel 7, but when I try to install with "laravel new newproject" I can't get past php errors.

php -v shows

```
PHP 7.1.32 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2019 19:00:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

I have updated Homestead. vagrant box list now shows

```
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 9.2.0)
```

and I have added php72 using Homebrew.

But I am still stuck with php 7.1

Please help. Laravel install page is a useless few lines.

Comment: What happens with the PHP version after running `brew link php72`?

Comment: I get a "no such keg" error

Comment: But I also thought using Homestead meant I didn't need to install PHP separately? I I feel like I shouldn't use Homebrew to fix the Homestead problem.

Comment: Use `MacPorts`... way better than `Homescrewed`.